How to setup boilerplate of css in VScode
"Print to console": {
    "prefix": "boilerplate",
    "body": [
        "* {",
        "    padding: 0;",
        "    margin: 0;",
        "    box-sizing: border-box;",
        "}",
        "",
        "body {",
        "    height: 100vh;",
        "    width: 100vw;",
        "}"
    ],
    "description": "Log output to console"
}

}
I have typed this code in my vscode source.css.styled.jason but not working can you tell me solution like it will not suggest me any recommendation for my boiler plate.
I am expecting to get my boilerplate just after typing in the VS Code like boilerplate.

You should find a file named css.json under preferences > Configure snippets.
You should update "Print to console" to "CSS Boilerplate" as the former is not used to set up CSS Boilerplate code.
Use the updated code below:
{
  "CSS Boilerplate": {
     "prefix": "boilerplate",
    "body": [
      "* {",
      "    padding: 0;",
      "    margin: 0;",
      "    box-sizing: border-box;",
      "}",
      "",
      "body {",
      "    height: 100vh;",
      "    width: 100vw;",
      "}"
    ],
    "description": "Basic CSS boilerplate with reset and full-screen setup"
  }
}

